# What is build and passing button in github?

Tags: github

[image]

I guess those something related to project deployment tools. Actually what are those, how to add those and what is the benefit of those?

**Edit 1**
Is there any billing issue(payment) with those or those are free?

Answer (score 9):

They're known as [**Code Repository Badges**](https://github.com/dwyl/repo-badges), and detail various aspects of the general stability of the repository. There are a number of badges available, but the most common are:

- `build: passing`: Indicates that the project's tests are all passing. This is usually set up through **[Travis-CI](https://github.com/dwyl/learn-travis)** integration.
- `coverage`: How much of the project is tested. `75%` of the code in your image has been through passing unit tests.
- `dependenices`: How many dependencies the repository has on other repositories in order to **run**
- `devDependencies`: How many dependencies the repository has on other repositories in order to **develop**

Answer (score 1):

#### What are they

These are "badges". Badges are offered by all kinds of build tools, package managers and so on.

Say you're using AppVeyor to do your continuous integration and deployments, in your project settings in AppVeyor they provide a HTML / markdown snippet for you to embed in places like GitHub to show everyone looking at your GitHub readme that the last build was successful.

Badges are typically (but not always) dynamic in the sense that the service provider (npm, AppVeyor, etc) will serve the badge from a URL (in the code snippet you get) and when a client grabs that image it will show the latest state of the badge's data (build succeeded/failed, available on npm, tests failing, code coverage %, etc.).

#### How to use them

You get the snippet of code from the service provider (npm, AppVeyor, etc) and just paste it straight into your readme or wherever you like.

#### What's the benefit

This varies obviously depending on what the badge is showing, but some examples would be:

- **Build status badge:** Tells you whether or not the latest code in the current branch can be built. Useful for quickly showing people there's WIP or issues with the codebase.
- **Code coverage badge:** Tells you the % of code covered by unit tests. Useful if you came across a GitHub repo and wanted to know the quality of the code base and unit test coverage if that is important to you.
- **Tests passing badge:** How many tests are passing/failing. Similar to build failed status gives you a quick red light as a potential consumer of this library, or even as a dev on the team that `Houston, we have a problem`.
- **NPM badges:** Version badges, available, download count, etc. are all useful info indicators to people.
- **Misc. static badges:** Some services/libraries offer badges that are just static and usually for promotional purposes of their library/brand/service. Framework X might create a badge with their logo/name and developers who like it can say that their website/framework depends on/uses Framework X by putting that badge in their own readme.
- The possibilies are endless.

Answer (score 1):

These are something known as **Code Repository Badges**.

To quote [an online resource](https://github.com/dwyl/repo-badges):

> As people who are passionate about writing great code we display "badges" in our code repositories to signal to fellow developers that we set ourselves high standards for the code we write, think of them as the software-equivalent of the brand on your jeans or other reliable product.

In short, it's a way to say that "hey, look, my GitHub project has a high standard!". The link above actually goes into a fair bit of detail on the different badges, but let me just point out two common ones shown in your picture:

1. "Build passing"

This makes use of continuous integration tools like [Travis CI](https://travis-ci.org/) which will help to build and test your code when you push code onto a GitHub repository (given that you have set up Travis CI for that repository).

Using this can ensure that no breaking changes get merged into your project, and also prevents wasting reviewers' time and effort on pull requests that are not "working".

2. "Coverage"

This measures how much code in your GitHub project is actually tested. It makes use of tools like [Codecov](https://codecov.io/), again premised on the fact that you have set up such tools for your repository.

Using this can remind contributors to write proper tests for the code, so that any potential bugs in the code can be detected.

As you can see, the badges help to ensure that your project maintains a certain standard, which can improve your project quality, and even attract people to work on your project (e.g. in the case of open-source software hosted on GitHub).